# Is there a spell that could possibly shape metal?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Is there a spell that I can shape small amounts of metal into other metal objects? Say you have a small lump of metal could you turn that into a fork? Or could you turn the iron in a person's blood into a needles or nails?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: When asking such short questions, it is kinda expected that you try searching yourself, for example on D&D Beyond, like https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=transmutation and tell us why you are not happy with what you found.

Answer (score 4):

[*Fabricate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate), a 4th level transmutation spell for the wizard, artificer and forge domain clerics.

> You convert raw materials into products of the same material. For example, you can fabricate a wooden bridge from a clump of trees, a rope from a patch of hemp, and clothes from flax or wool.
>
> Choose raw materials that you can see within range. You can fabricate a Large or smaller object (contained within a 10-foot cube, or eight connected 5-foot cubes), given a sufficient quantity of raw material. If you are working with metal, stone, or another mineral substance, however, the fabricated object can be no larger than Medium (contained within a single 5-foot cube). The quality of objects made by the spell is commensurate with the quality of the raw materials.
>
> Creatures or magic items can't be created or transmuted by this spell. You also can't use it to create items that ordinarily require a high degree of craftsmanship, such as jewelry, weapons, glass, or armor, unless you have proficiency with the type of artisan's tools used to craft such objects.

I just went through [DnDbeyond's spell search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-class=8&filter-school=10&filter-search=&page=4&sort=level) with the Transmutation school. Filtered for Wizard because I was too lazy to dig through them all so I likely missed some.

Comment: Note that the raw material's quality determines the outcome -- raw ore could produce only crude implements, and it's up to your DM whether the iron in blood would even work at all for fabricating a fork.  But an average human contains only about 4 grams of iron, not all in the blood, and that's about enough to make four small paperclips, so it might have to be a pretty small fork *anyway* even if they allowed it.

Comment: Forge Cleric has a similar ability. It's not a spell so may be out of scope.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym oh yeah the famous "how many peoples blood do I need for a sword" question. Its a loooooooot of people. BUT: sewing needles are quite small, especially those for finer threads, so maaaybe *that* could work